# Coolant leak / engine overheat / cylinder misfire

Tags: coolant, overheating, misfire, hvac, head-gasket

Make: Honda

Model: Civic 1.8L 2007 petrol

Miles: 107,000

I have experienced cold air coming from heating system for a while - I probably should have addressed this sooner.

Finally when driving steadily on the motorway the amber engine warning light came on and the car went into  limp mode so I pulled over. I noticed immediately the temp gauge was at max. I could smell burning. So the engine has overheated.

Turns out it's pretty bad as 1) the dipstick has melted and snapped off in my hand the following morning when I went to check it after allowing it the night to cool. 2) The middle two ignition coil packs won't even pull out, so severe warping has occurred presumably? Maybe it's welded in there after the heat. Either way this is abysmal news.

There is basically no coolant in there so it must have come out via either a sudden leak or a slow leak I didn't notice. Inside of radiator cap itself has white goo (see photo: https://ibb.co/wB0Shj4).

The inside of the oil cap look okay fwiw, none of the white goo seen on the inside of the radiator cap.

These two photos show signs of coolant leak, but can't say for sure that they're very recent: [pic1](https://ibb.co/0FGBnDm) [pic2](https://ibb.co/tQGfxgh)

OBDII codes:

*P0117: Engine coolant temperature sensor 1 circuit low*

*P0303: Cylinder 3 misfire detected*

Q: any hope the engine not being toast given the melted dipstick and centre two coils won't even come out with a hard tug?
Q: likely any sense in swapping the engine out given it's the EX trim, or just move on and don't open that can of worms?